# The first layer does not appear on the map using WMS in openlayers. What I'm missing?

Tags: openlayers, wms

I'm trying to shown on the map the layer with the url  , but I can not find the solution. However with the second layer it works. What I miss? And why?

I made this fiddle:

And yes, I have tried to change the projection, and even remove it.The layer would have to appear to the northwest of Africa, Canary Islands

EDIT:
My bad sorry

link: http://idecan1.grafcan.es/ServicioWMS/MTL

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/nzx9fvz5/2/

```
var projec = new ol.proj.Projection({
  code: "EPSG:32628"
});
  var map = new ol.Map({
    layers: [
      new ol.layer.Tile({
        source: new ol.source.OSM()
      }),
      new ol.layer.Tile({
        source: new ol.source.TileWMS({
          url: "http://idecan1.grafcan.es/ServicioWMS/MTL",
          params: {'LAYERS': "LIDAR_MTL"},
          projection: projec
        })
      }),
      new ol.layer.Tile({
        source: new ol.source.TileWMS({
          url: "https://mesonet.agron.iastate.edu/cgi-bin/wms/us/mrms.cgi",
          params: {'LAYERS': "mrms"}
        })
      })
    ],
    target: 'map',
    view: new ol.View({
      center: [0, 0],
      zoom: 2
    })
  });
```

Comment: What fiddle?  It is better I think to post the code in the question

Comment: The URL you give does not appear to go anywhere

Comment: Your URL labeled "link" doesn't show anything, which may be why it doesn't display a layer.  Please confirm that URL is correct

Comment: Are you sure you request a WMS and not a WFS? See this http://idecan1.grafcan.es/ServicioWMS/MTL?LAYERS=LIDAT_MTL&request=GetCapabilities&service=WFS vs http://idecan1.grafcan.es/ServicioWMS/MTL?LAYERS=LIDAT_MTL&request=GetCapabilities&service=WMS

Comment: You can put http://idecan1.grafcan.es/ServicioWMS/MTL or http://idecan1.grafcan.es/ServicioWMS/MTL?LAYERS=LIDAT_MTL&request=GetCapabilities&service=WMS 
it should work. 
I've never worked with wfs, but I do not think it's that

Comment: My point is that it seems it is a WFS, not a WMS. BTW, can you open this WMS in ArcGIS or QGIS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, the layer doesn't support png, only jpeg. So you need to especify the format:

```
... 
params: {'LAYERS': "WMS_LIDAR_MTL",
                   'FORMAT': 'image/jpeg'},
...
```

Answer (score 1):

As is often the case with these questions you need to look at the [server capabilities](http://idecan1.grafcan.es/ServicioWMS/MTL?service=wms&request=getcapabilities). This tells us it is a WMS and that it has one layer:

```
<Layer>
<Name>WMS_LIDAR_MTL</Name>
<Title>WMS LIDAR MTL</Title>
<Abstract>
Modelo de Terreno Lidar (MTL) generado con datos LIDAR. Propiedad de GRAFCAN. Esta información es libre y gratuita. Se prohibe la descarga masiva de información.
</Abstract>
<KeywordList>
<Keyword>WMS</Keyword>
<Keyword>MTL</Keyword>
<Keyword>LIDAR</Keyword>
<Keyword>MODELO</Keyword>
<Keyword>DIGITAL</Keyword>
<Keyword>MDS</Keyword>
<Keyword>MDT</Keyword>
<Keyword>CANARIAS</Keyword>
<Keyword>GRAFCAN</Keyword>
</KeywordList>
<CRS>EPSG:32628</CRS>
<CRS>EPSG:4326</CRS>
<CRS>EPSG:32627</CRS>
<EX_GeographicBoundingBox>
<westBoundLongitude>-18.3099</westBoundLongitude>
<eastBoundLongitude>-13.1373</eastBoundLongitude>
<southBoundLatitude>26.1839</southBoundLatitude>
<northBoundLatitude>29.8305</northBoundLatitude>
</EX_GeographicBoundingBox>
<BoundingBox CRS="EPSG:32628" minx="180000" miny="2.9e+06" maxx="680000" maxy="3.3e+06"/>
<Layer queryable="1" opaque="0" cascaded="0">
<Name>LIDAR_MTL</Name>
<Title>Modelo Terreno LIDAR</Title>
<CRS>EPSG:32628</CRS>
<EX_GeographicBoundingBox>
<westBoundLongitude>-19.0427</westBoundLongitude>
<eastBoundLongitude>-12.52</eastBoundLongitude>
<southBoundLatitude>26.5097</southBoundLatitude>
<northBoundLatitude>30.0268</northBoundLatitude>
</EX_GeographicBoundingBox>
<BoundingBox CRS="EPSG:32628" minx="109794" miny="2.93809e+06" maxx="739222" maxy="3.32176e+06"/>
</Layer>
</Layer>
```

Looking closer we can see it supports exactly 3 projections (epsg:32628, epsg:32627 & epgs:4326), while in your code you never set the projection of the map so it defaults to epsg:3857 which the server doesn't know.

So something like this should work:

```
proj4.defs("EPSG:32628","+proj=utm +zone=28 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs");
var projec = new ol.proj.Projection({
  code: "EPSG:32628",
  extent: [166021.44, 0.00, 534994.66, 9329005.18],
  units: 'm'
});
ol.proj.addProjection(projec);
var map = new ol.Map({
  layers: [
    new ol.layer.Tile({
      source: new ol.source.OSM()
    }),
    new ol.layer.Tile({
      source: new ol.source.TileWMS({
        url: "http://idecan1.grafcan.es/ServicioWMS/MTL?service=wms",
        params: {
          'LAYERS': "LIDAR_MTL"
        },

      })
    })
  ],
  target: 'map',
  view: new ol.View({
    projection: 'EPSG:32628',

  })
});
```

Comment: I have this in the head of the page <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/proj4js/2.4.3/proj4.js"></script>
    <script src="http://epsg.io/32628.js"></script> to define the projection. however i have tried your code and doesn't work.